# is there a way to calculate balance in mysql view?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

i want to calculate the balance  from mysql

```
200  
270 
295 
285 
270 
250
```

I try but not work

```
SELECT `id`, `in`, `out`,balance
FROM (SELECT t.*,
         @n := IF(@g <> id, 0, @n) + COALESCE(in,0) - COALESCE(out, 0) balance,
         @g := id 
      FROM product_trans t,
          (SELECT @n := 0) n,
          (SELECT @g := 0) g ORDER BY id ) q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, SUM(t2.`in` - t2.`out`) AS balance
FROM tab t1
JOIN tab t2
  ON t2.id <= t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY t1.id;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c76f/5/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═════════╗
║ id  ║ balance ║
╠═════╬═════════╣
║  1  ║     200 ║
║  2  ║     270 ║
║  3  ║     295 ║
║  4  ║     285 ║
║  5  ║     270 ║
║  6  ║     250 ║
╚═════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a variable to calculate a running sum:

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf9d/3/0

```
set @runsum:=0;

select id, (@runsum := @runsum + `in` - `out`) as runner
  from product_trans
order by id;
```

In most databases other than MySQL, like Oracle or SQL Server, you would use analytic functions instead.